# How to authenticate that user owns twitter account?

Tags: twitter, user-accounts

I'm developing a social network. Users may register and share their twitter username (if they want). Wherever the user posts a comment or other content, his username is displayed. I would like to display the follow @userTwitter button, if the user has set the twitter account.

Now, everything works, the problem is to validate that the user is the owner of that twitter account. Right now the user could be entering any valid twitter account! Maybe using the Twitter api?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your app up as a Twitter client, this way your user has to log into twitter to authorize your app, thereby verifying their twitter identity.

This is a couple years old but might be enough to get you started:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/

Comment: My website is not going to use or send twitts on behalf of the user or anything like that. I just would like to have proof that the user owns that twitter account.

Comment: You can be a twitter app that does not ask for these privileges. You are simply authenticating rather than authorizing. Check this out: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth